# The issue about Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'A'

Tags: typescript, enums, interface, vuejs3, typescript-generics

Assume that enum type, an interface,a reactive data form, and a specified data array with Typescript in VUE3 are as follows

```js
enum A {
  GIRL = "Girl",
  BOY = "Boy",
}

interface AI {
  a: A;
}
const opt = reactive<AI>({
  a: A.GIRL,
})
const optArr = [
  {
    category: "a",
    buts: [A.GIRL, A.BOY],
  },
]
```

When trying to modify some value in **opt** (reverse the string value),

```js
 let str = opt[optArr[0].category as keyof typeof opt]
 opt[optArr[0].category as keyof typeof opt] = str.split("").reverse().join("")
 console.log( opt[optArr[0].category as keyof typeof opt]  )
```

The output result is correct: 'lriG'. However, I got an error message **Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)** from the line of

```js
opt[optArr[0].category as keyof typeof opt] = str.split("").reverse().join("")
```

Does anyone know how to fix the above error?

PS. I try to use generic data type in opt and optArr as follows

```js
const opt = reactive({
  a: "Girl",
})
const optArr = [
  {
    category: "a",
    buts: ["Girl", "Boy"],
  },
];
```

There is no the above error message.

Comment: What is the `reactive<T>` generic? If it's from an external library, you should probably include it your question tags.

Comment: Here reactive is used in VUE3.

Comment: I get `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'A'`

Comment: Is this correct? https://tsplay.dev/wgQJMm

Comment: @Dimava In tsplay.dev/wgQJMm , the error message is the same as mine, although the output result is correct.

Comment: Well, you are trying to assign `"lriG"` to `"Girl"` so ofc it errors